# Assigning class and placeholder to html option and select tags

Tags: html, semantics

Is it semantically incorrect to assign a class to `<option>` tag or `placeholder` on `<select>` tag?
Are there any other downsides of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class` is a [global attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes) in HTML5 and thus can be applied to `option` but `placeholder` isn't allowed on `select`. Why? Probably for practical/historical reasons as the first option is displayed in the select - of `size` < 2 - and doesn't leave room for displaying another text as in an empty `input[type="text"]`

How could you then achieve the same effect as a placeholder in a text input? Well you don't need it:

> ([HTML5 doc on placeholder](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute))
>   The placeholder attribute represents a short hint (a word or short phrase) intended to aid the user with data entry when the control has no value.

- Selecting an option doesn't need any data entry (a date does need a format indicated, like mm/dd/aaaa or dd/mm/aaaa...)
- There's already a label to indicate the purpose of the select (associated with `for/id` attributes on each)
- What should you put in the first option? That's an excellent question... Between `-------` ("*oh but then the user may not see the select*"), `Please select blah`, `(repeating the label)` and `first option but we'll never know if user did choose this option or forgot to select another one`... that's an ergonomics problem and not my field of expertise. ;)